# Typescript Union type with a function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to have a property with a union type of a lambda function or a string.

```
class TestClass {
    name: string | () => string;
}
```

Non-working TS playground sample can be accessed [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20TimePeriod%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%20%7C%20()%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D).

But the TS compiler gives an error: `"[ts] Member 'string' implicitly has an 'any' type."`

Is the type declared incorrectly? Or is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You just need an extra set of parenthesis.

```
class TestClass {
    name: string | (() => string);
}
```

The compiler is trying to do `(string | ()) => string` if you don't use them, because of precedence.

Answer (score 16):

As Titian already mentioned, you have to use parenthesis.

```
class TimePeriod {
    name: string | (() => string);
}
```

Another approach is to use a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases):

```
type ATypeName = () => string;
class TimePeriod {
    name: string | ATypeName;
}
```